# Join GPS data and video from UAV to get frames from specific locations

Tags: software-recommendations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, video

Is there any piece of software capable to present gps track simultaneously with video ie. google maps data and allowing to clip a frame on selected locations on track? Both data and video are from Phantom 3 Advance

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Qgis 3 plugin Video Uav Tracker.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I find VUT as a beta plugin to earlier version of qgis and it did what i want to ;)